# Syntax error on "else"

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error, token

I keep getting this error: "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token." I tried to move things around, but nothing is working. I am not sure how to fix this.

```
     if (input == "yes")
        System.out.println("Enter exam 1 score:");
        examScore1 = keyboard.nextInt();

     if (input == "y" )  
        System.out.println("Enter exam 1 score:");
        examScore1 = keyboard.nextInt();

    else {
            System.out.println("Do you know your lab average?");
        }
```

Comment: This is why you should always use braces `{}` with `if` statements.

Comment: Also you should use `equals` to compare strings in Java not with `=`.

Comment: What is strange is that you used `{` `}` where you could skip them, but at the same time you didn't use them where they ware needed. You probably need to read more about "scope" in Java.

Answer (score 3):

There are two clear problems with your code, and one small style point.

1. Java doesn't use indentation to indicate scope - where a conditional block starts and ends.  By default, a condition is just one line.  It's usually considered good practice to use `{` and `}` to delimit a conditional block.  In other words, don't write this

   ```
   if (something)
        one;
        two;
        three;
   ```

   because only `one;` here depends on the condition.  Put the whole lot between `{` and `}`, like

   ```
   if (something) {
       one;
       two;
       three;
   }
   ```
2. The next problem is that String values need to be compared with the `equals` method, rather than with `==`.  The reason is that `==` checks whether two expressions reference the exact same object.  It doesn't check whether two objects have the same content.  In this particular case, the object that you've read from input will never be the same as your `String` literal, so a condition like `if (input == "yes")` will always be false.
3. Since you've got the same logic repeated in two conditional blocks, it would be a good idea to write that logic only once.  In this case, you can use the `||`  operator (which means "or") to combine the two conditions.

Fixing these three issues all at once would turn your code into this.

```
if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y")) {
    System.out.println("Enter exam 1 score:");
    examScore1 = keyboard.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.println("Do you know your lab average?");
}
```

And here, because the `else` immediately follows a conditional block, the compiler can make sense of it, and you won't get the compile error.